# Hide and Show function, how can i solve it?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a question about hide function.

I have:
2 Buttons `Button_Zeritifikat1` and `Button_Zertifikat2`

2 labels with image `labal_zertifikat1` and `label_Zeritifikat2`

2 labels which shows the page number(in german) `label_seite1` and `labal_seite2`

if I start my app it shows the first image and first labal which shows the page number.

if I press my button it shows the label_seite2 but it doesn not hides the label_seite1 so my question is, is the ".hide" function wrong? how can I hide the label_seite2 ?

**Its mine Window**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Ui_Zertifikat(object):
    def setupUi(self, WindowZertifikat):
        self.myWindowZertifikat = WindowZertifikat
        WindowZertifikat.setObjectName("Form")
        WindowZertifikat.setGeometry(300,300,822,566)

        self.label_Zertifikat1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(WindowZertifikat)
        self.label_Zertifikat1.setGeometry(0,0,822,494)
        self.label_Zertifikat1.setPixmap(QPixmap("./image/speichern.png"))

        self.label_seite1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.label_seite1.setGeometry(361,495,100,30)
        self.label_seite1.setText("Seite 1 von 2")
        self.label_seite1.setStyleSheet(
        "QLabel{color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-weight:550}"
        )




        self.Button_Zertifikat1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.Button_Zertifikat1.setGeometry(422,530,130,30)
        self.Button_Zertifikat1.setText("Nächste Seite")
        self.Button_Zertifikat1.setStyleSheet(
        "QPushButton{background-color: #0000FF; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black; color:white; font-size:10pt; font-weight:500}"
        "QPushButton:hover{background-color: #08088A; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"
        )

        self.Button_Zertifikat2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.Button_Zertifikat2.setGeometry(270,530,130,30)
        self.Button_Zertifikat2.setText("Vorherige Seite")
        self.Button_Zertifikat2.setStyleSheet(
        "QPushButton{background-color: #0000FF; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black; color:white; font-size:10pt; font-weight:500}"
        "QPushButton:hover{background-color: #08088A; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"
        )    




        self.Button_Zertifikat1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ZertifikatSeiten(0))
        self.Button_Zertifikat2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ZertifikatSeiten(1))        


    def ZertifikatSeiten(self, b):
        self.label_Zertifikat2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.label_Zertifikat2.setGeometry(0,0,822,494)
        self.label_Zertifikat2.setPixmap(QPixmap("./image/umbenennen.png"))

        self.label_Zertifikat1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.label_Zertifikat1.setGeometry(0,0,822,494)
        self.label_Zertifikat1.setPixmap(QPixmap("./image/speichern.png"))        

        self.label_seite1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.label_seite1.setGeometry(361,495,100,30)
        self.label_seite1.setText("Seite 1 von 2")
        self.label_seite1.setStyleSheet(
        "QLabel{color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-weight:550}"
        )

        self.label_seite2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.label_seite2.setGeometry(361,495,100,30)
        self.label_seite2.setText("Seite 2 von 2")
        self.label_seite2.setStyleSheet(
        "QLabel{color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-weight:550}"
        )

        if b == 0:

            self.label_Zertifikat2.show()
            self.label_seite2.show()
            self.label_seite1.hide()



        elif b == 1:

            self.label_Zertifikat1.show()
            self.label_seite1.show()
            self.label_seite2.hide()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    WindowZertifikat = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Zertifikat()
    ui.setupUi(WindowZertifikat)
    WindowZertifikat.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: provide  a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I added my button.

Comment: I think you have not read the link, your code is not an MRE

Comment: @eyllanesc I read it but i dont know if I understand correctly.. so I edit my complete code and Question. Hope its now good and I can find a salution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are creating new QLabels every time you press the button. Instead you must create the QLabels only once and only hide the necessary QLabels.

```py
class Ui_Zertifikat(object):
    def setupUi(self, WindowZertifikat):
        self.myWindowZertifikat = WindowZertifikat
        WindowZertifikat.setObjectName("Form")
        WindowZertifikat.setGeometry(300, 300, 822, 566)

        self.label_Zertifikat1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(WindowZertifikat)
        self.label_Zertifikat1.setGeometry(0, 0, 822, 494)
        self.label_Zertifikat1.setPixmap(QPixmap("./image/speichern.png"))

        self.label_seite1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.label_seite1.setGeometry(361, 495, 100, 30)
        self.label_seite1.setText("Seite 1 von 2")
        self.label_seite1.setStyleSheet(
            "QLabel{color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-weight:550}"
        )

        self.label_Zertifikat2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.label_Zertifikat2.setGeometry(0, 0, 822, 494)
        self.label_Zertifikat2.setPixmap(QPixmap("./image/umbenennen.png"))

        self.label_seite2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.label_seite2.setGeometry(361, 495, 100, 30)
        self.label_seite2.setText("Seite 2 von 2")
        self.label_seite2.setStyleSheet(
            "QLabel{color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-weight:550}"
        )

        self.Button_Zertifikat1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.Button_Zertifikat1.setGeometry(422, 530, 130, 30)
        self.Button_Zertifikat1.setText("Nächste Seite")
        self.Button_Zertifikat1.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton{background-color: #0000FF; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black; color:white; font-size:10pt; font-weight:500}"
            "QPushButton:hover{background-color: #08088A; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"
        )

        self.Button_Zertifikat2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.Button_Zertifikat2.setGeometry(270, 530, 130, 30)
        self.Button_Zertifikat2.setText("Vorherige Seite")
        self.Button_Zertifikat2.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton{background-color: #0000FF; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black; color:white; font-size:10pt; font-weight:500}"
            "QPushButton:hover{background-color: #08088A; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"
        )

        self.Button_Zertifikat1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ZertifikatSeiten(0))
        self.Button_Zertifikat2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ZertifikatSeiten(1))

        self.ZertifikatSeiten(1)

    def ZertifikatSeiten(self, b):
        if b == 0:
            self.label_Zertifikat2.show()
            self.label_seite2.show()
            self.label_Zertifikat1.hide()
            self.label_seite1.hide()

        elif b == 1:
            self.label_Zertifikat1.show()
            self.label_seite1.show()
            self.label_Zertifikat2.hide()
            self.label_seite2.hide()
```

Another much simpler solution would be just to change the text and QPixmap without the need to create n QLabels

```
class Ui_Zertifikat(object):
    def setupUi(self, WindowZertifikat):
        self.myWindowZertifikat = WindowZertifikat
        WindowZertifikat.setObjectName("Form")
        WindowZertifikat.setGeometry(300, 300, 822, 566)

        self.label_Zertifikat1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(WindowZertifikat)
        self.label_Zertifikat1.setGeometry(0, 0, 822, 494)
        self.label_Zertifikat1.setPixmap(QPixmap("./image/speichern.png"))

        self.label_seite1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.label_seite1.setGeometry(361, 495, 100, 30)
        self.label_seite1.setText("Seite 1 von 2")
        self.label_seite1.setStyleSheet(
            "QLabel{color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-weight:550}"
        )

        self.Button_Zertifikat1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.Button_Zertifikat1.setGeometry(422, 530, 130, 30)
        self.Button_Zertifikat1.setText("Nächste Seite")
        self.Button_Zertifikat1.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton{background-color: #0000FF; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black; color:white; font-size:10pt; font-weight:500}"
            "QPushButton:hover{background-color: #08088A; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"
        )

        self.Button_Zertifikat2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.myWindowZertifikat)
        self.Button_Zertifikat2.setGeometry(270, 530, 130, 30)
        self.Button_Zertifikat2.setText("Vorherige Seite")
        self.Button_Zertifikat2.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton{background-color: #0000FF; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black; color:white; font-size:10pt; font-weight:500}"
            "QPushButton:hover{background-color: #08088A; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: Black}"
        )

        self.Button_Zertifikat1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ZertifikatSeiten(0))
        self.Button_Zertifikat2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ZertifikatSeiten(1))

        self.ZertifikatSeiten(1)

    def ZertifikatSeiten(self, b):
        if b == 0:
            self.label_Zertifikat1.setText("Seite 2 von 2")
            self.label_seite1.setPixmap(QPixmap("./image/umbenennen.png"))

        elif b == 1:
            self.label_Zertifikat1.setText("Seite 1 von 2")
            self.label_seite1.setPixmap(QPixmap("./image/speichern.png"))
```

Comment: @CihanDinçel 1) Did you realize that the initial code you provided could not help you? 2) It would be advisable for the name of the variables to be in English since they are easier to handle for the community.

Comment: yes.. okay i will be keep in mind thanks for the advise